# Shutdown callback from Jetty to Restlet?

Tags: jetty, restlet, db4o

I have been developing a Restlet Application where the db4o database gets opened and closed in the ServerResource or classes below. I started to run into concurrency issues so changed the db4o to the embedded client server mode and had to open the database file in the Restlet Application.

Question is where do I close the database ? During development previously, I was able to hot-swap the war files in jetty without any problems. Now, with the database opened at the Application, the database is not getting shutdown when I hot swap the war.

I have seen in some previous posts about a servlet listener, however, I am using Restlet JavaSE and do not have access to these packages.

How do I signal my Application that the war is being closed out, or jetty is being shutdown ? Thank you...

Restlet 2.0.11 JavaSE, Jetty 8.0.4